# CoreAnimations is too slow for my app: which technology should I move to?

Tags: performance, core-animation

So I'm making the colouring app for my client. CoreGraphics was fun to use, but when dealing with detailed images (800+ CAShapeLayers) it became very slow on zooming/panning.

AFAIK CoreAnimation was not intended for such use. So I need to move to some engine/library.

The task requires:
-- layers
-- masking
-- Bezier paths and filling them
-- scaling, etc.

SpriteKit was my first choice, but it does not have proper (antialiased) masking.

Any advice?

Comment: iOS or macOS? Are the graphics interactive or just display of data? Did you subclass CALayers? How is the drawing done? Do you create your own CGContext? Is there also drawing of text? Were you able to measure the bottleneck to find where exactly the performance was hit?

Comment: Hello! Thanks for helping me out. 1. It's iOS 2. Graphics are interactive 3. Yes, I subclass CAShapeLayers. 4. The drawing is done by putting CAShapeLayers as subviews to UIView layer. 5. I do not create my own CGContext 6. No text there 7. I couldn't measure the bottleneck because my app crashes without any logs when using Instruments and I cannot find a solution for it yet.

Comment: After experimenting I have found that masking CALayer causes all the performance problems.